# If statement based on return if a $.post command

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if (localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != null && localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != "")
{
  var courseSectionID = localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'];
  alert("BEFORE :" + courseSectionID);
  var postData = { 'courseSectionID': courseSectionID };
  $.post('/Course/CourseSectionLaunchStillExistCheck/', postData, function (data)
  {
    if (data == "True") 
    {
      var id = parseInt(courseSectionID);
      alert("1: " + id);
    }
    else
    {
      var id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
      alert("2: " + id);
    }
  });
}
else
{
  var id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
  alert("3: " + id);
}

var urlstring = 'Section/' + id;
alert(urlstring);
```

If I enter at alert 3 I am always getting the correct **Section/115** etc as expected but when I enter through alert points 1 and 2 I am getting the error returned as **Section/undefined** but the alert strings at point 1 and 2 have the correct value so I cannot understand why these are undefined at the setting or the urlstring im sure im doing something really dumb but i cant seem to see what it is any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! The server didn't reply yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the definition of `var id` once outside the first `if` as follows and try.

```
var id = null;
if (localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != null && localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != "")
{
  var courseSectionID = localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'];
  alert("BEFORE :" + courseSectionID);
  var postData = { 'courseSectionID': courseSectionID };
  $.post('/Course/CourseSectionLaunchStillExistCheck/', postData, function (data)
  {
    if (data == "True") 
    {
      id = parseInt(courseSectionID);
      alert("1: " + id);
    }
    else
    {
      id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
      alert("2: " + id);
    }
  });
}
else
{
  id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
  alert("3: " + id);
}

var urlstring = 'Section/' + id;
alert(urlstring);
```

Comment: since the $.post() is asynchronous there is a chance the the alert will print Section/null

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using a callback function since the ajax request made by $.post() is asynchronous by default. 
I haven't tested the code.

```
//receives a callback function as parameter to print the id.
myFunction(printFunction);//see declaration of printFunction below


//prints the id
function printFunction(id) {
    var urlstring = 'Section/' + id;
    alert(urlstring);
}


function myFunction(callbackFunctionAsParameter) {

    if (localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] !== null && localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] !== "") {
        var courseSectionID = localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'];
        var postData = {
            'courseSectionID': courseSectionID
        };

        //by default all ajax requests are sent asynchronously in jquery => http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
        $.post('/Course/CourseSectionLaunchStillExistCheck/', postData, function (data) {
            var id = null;

            if (data == "True") {
                id = parseInt(courseSectionID);
            } else {
                id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
            }

            callbackFunctionAsParameter(id); //print here
        });
    } else {
        var id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
        callbackFunctionAsParameter(id); //print here
    }

}
```

Comment: This was working fine with my alert statements included but on removal of these I am still getting undefined as per the asynchronous post, I have tried to use setTimeout to wait for this but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Are you removing the alert(..) in printFunction or the calls to callbackFunctionAsParameter(id) ?